How to obtain access token to create a repository in github enterprise using an App
I have a service that executes requests on behalf of a user on a github enterprise server.
I'm trying to add a "create repository" operation to provide my users with.
The basic JWT token I use for every other operation does not work for this flow.
Trying to acquire an access token for an app installation results in {"message":"Resource not accessible by integration","docume ntation_url":"https://docs.github.com/enterprise-server@3.8/rest/reference/repos#create-an-organization-repository"}
Following the link to the documentation leads to a how to acquire a token during the installation process, where you get a code to use for token generation, but this is not the installation phase any more.
The permissions my app has are:
{actions=write, actions_variables=write, administration=write, checks=write,
codespaces=write, contents=write, environments=write, issues=write, metadata=read, pull_requests=write, repository_projects=admin, statuses=write, workflows=write}

Tried https://.../app/installations/${installationId}/access_tokens.
Expected to get a token to use with `https://.../user/repos"
or "https://.../orgs/{my_org_id}/repos"
The result is {"message":"Resource not accessible by integration","docume ntation_url":"https://docs.github.com/enterprise-server@3.8/rest/reference/repos#create-an-organization-repository"}
This happens for both the user installation id token and JWT token.
I asked github's support but they only direct me to the documentation where I get stuck where every process along the way requires to run only on the first time the app is installed, but no details on how to run the day to day flows of creating a repository.
Please provide the steps and requirements to create a repository, either on the org level or user level, but anything that will work.
Thanks.
